# Rapid way to find min and max values of a property in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, minimax

i have an array of objects like this:

```
arr = [
    {name: "Alex", value: 1}, 
    {name: "Bill", value: 2},
    {name: "Jim",  value: 3},
    {name: "Dim",  value: 5}
]
```

I want quick and clean way to have the min an max values of the value property

```
min = 1,
max = 5
```

Comment: are item.value arranged by order?

Comment: Nope, it's in random order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most performant would probably be a simple loop

```js
arr = [
    {name: "Alex", value: 1}, 
    {name: "Bill", value: 2},
    {name: "Jim",  value: 3},
    {name: "Dim",  value: 5}
]

let min,max;

for (var i=arr.length; i--;) {
  if ((!min) || arr[i].value < min) min = arr[i].value;
  if ((!max) || arr[i].value > max) max = arr[i].value;
}

console.log(min, max)
```

Shortest to write, something like

```js
arr = [
    {name: "Alex", value: 1}, 
    {name: "Bill", value: 2},
    {name: "Jim",  value: 3},
    {name: "Dim",  value: 5}
]

let m=Math,a=arr.map(z=>z.value);let [min,max]=[m.min(...a),m.max(...a)];

console.log(min,max)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `reduce` function on an array for min:

```
arr.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
    return prev.value < curr.value ? prev : curr;
});
```

max would work in a similar way

Answer (score 1):

```js
var min = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY,
    max = Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;

arr.forEach(function(obj) {
   min = Math.min(min, obj.value);
   max = Math.max(max, obj.value);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map()` to return array of values and then use `Math.max/min` with spread syntax.

```js
var arr = [{name:'Alex', value:1}, {name:'Bill', value:2},{name:'Jim', value: 3},{name: 'Dim', value:5}]

var values = arr.map(e => e.value);
var min = Math.min(...values);
var max = Math.max(...values);

console.log(max)
console.log(min)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could either `map` the values and use `Math` function to get highest and the lowest value.

```js
var arr = [{name:'Alex', value:1}, {name:'Bill', value:2},{name:'Jim', value: 3},{name: 'Dim', value:5}],
    hash = arr.map(v => v.value),
    min = Math.min.apply(Math, hash),
    max = Math.max.apply(Math, hash);
    
    console.log(min, max);
```

Or just sort the array of object based on the `value` property and choose the first and the last one.

```js
var arr = [{name:'Alex', value:1}, {name:'Bill', value:2},{name:'Jim', value: 3},{name: 'Dim', value:5}],
    hash = arr.sort((a,b) => a.value - b.value);
    min = hash[0].value;
    max = hash[hash.length-1].value;
    
    console.log(min, max);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function to do it for you, and every time you need to find the min/max, it only takes you one line:

```
function findMM (arr) {
    var minV;
    var maxV;
    var firstLoop = true;
    arr.forEach(function(object){
        if (firstLoop) {
            minV = object.value;
            maxV = object.value;
            firstLoop = false;
        } else {
            if (object.value < minV){ minV = object.value }
            if (object.value > maxV){ maxV = object.value }
        }
    });
    return {min: minV, max: maxV};
}

//using the function
var results = findMM(arr);
console.log(JSON.stringify(results)); //output: {"min":1,"max":5}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could sort your array using native `Array.prototype.sort()` and take the first and last value.

```js
let data = [{
    name: 'Ales',
    value: 1
  },
  {
    name: 'Dim',
    value: 5
  },
  {
    name: 'Bill',
    value: 2
  },
  {
    name: 'Jim',
    value: 3
  }
];

data = data.sort((a, b) => a.value - b.value);

let min = data [0].value;
let max = data [data .length - 1].value;


console.log('min:',  min);
console.log('max:', max)
```

Notes:

If you use instead:

```
let min = data [0];
let max = data [data .length - 1];
```

you could return the full object which has a minimum or maximum value, which could be handy.

Comment: I was trying to type "epic" but stackoverflow imposes a minimum amount of characters per comment, so yeah, this is my jibberish

Answer (score 1):

Using [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
var arr = [{name:'Alex', value:1}, {name:'Bill', value:2},{name:'Jim', value: 3},{name: 'Dim', value:5}]

var result = arr.reduce(function(acc, val){
    return { min: Math.min(acc.min, val.value),
            max: Math.max(acc.max, val.value)}
    }, {min: arr[0].value, max: arr[0].value});

console.log(result.max);
console.log(result.min);
```